# Using backgrounddownloader and savefilepicker together?

Tags: windows-runtime

Hello everyone I have a small winrt aplication that downloads video from internet and I was trying to implement backgrounddownloader and filesavepicker together but I run on errors for every type of implementation I searched google and I searched microsoft documentation but nothing.I implemented download via HttpClient class but what I want is to get download progress and HttpClient doesn't offer it.Thx in advance

Comment: You should add some information about what the problem actually is (error message etc) and maybe what language (C++, C# or JavaScript) you're developing in.

Comment: And please tell us some more about what you've tried and the errors you have encountered.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick sample, how to do it:

```
// set download URI
var uri = new Uri("http://s3.amazonaws.com/thetabletshow/thetabletshow_0072_lhotka.mp3");
// get destination file
var picker = new FileSavePicker();
// set allowed extensions
picker.FileTypeChoices.Add("MP3", new List<string> { ".mp3" });
var file = await picker.PickSaveFileAsync();

// create a background download
var downloader = new BackgroundDownloader();
var download = downloader.CreateDownload(uri, file);

// create progress object
var progress = new Progress<DownloadOperation>();
// attach an event handler to get notified on progress
progress.ProgressChanged += (o, operation) => 
    { 
        // use the progress info in Progress.BytesReceived and Progress.TotalBytesToReceive
        ProgressText.Text = operation.Progress.BytesReceived.ToString(); 
    };
// start the actual download
await download.StartAsync().AsTask(progress);
```

You should be able to modify it for your needs from here on.